# Google sheet group column data and display values in row

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, pivot

I have a Google sheet with values like:

```
Column 1     Column 2
----------|--------------
A           256
A           271
B           270
C           262
A           266
C           258
D           257
```

I want to transform the data into the following:

```
Column 1       Column 2      Column 3       Column 4      Column 5
-----------|--------------|-------------|--------------|------------
A            256             271          266
B            270
C            262             258
D            257
```

I want to group the distinct values of Column 1 and then for each value add them to columns for that value.

I don't have a lot of experience with pivot tables but I could not get it to work because the values were looking for aggregates of some kind like SUM or COUNT.  I don't want to aggregate, I want to list in columns all the values found for the group.

I hope this makes sense.

Anyone have any ideas how to do this.  I am comfortable with APP Scripts but was hoping there was a quicker way than dozens of lines of code building a custom sheet.

### EDIT #1: Peter's Answer

hi peter, thanks for the answer, the following works great for the first step

```
=SORT(unique('HOURS & MILEAGE LOG'!D7:D))
```

but the second step is not working for me.  It is just copying the same values for every row.  In the real sheet the unique column is actually D and it starts at D:7 and the values to be filled out across in the row are from column A:7 and down: see the following screen shot:

[image]

so I switched the transpose formula to:

```
=transpose(filter('HOURS & MILEAGE LOG'!A:A,'HOURS & MILEAGE LOG'!D:D=D8))
```

and this is the result:[image]

the values you see are header rows for the type of vehicle, CHIEF, PUMP, TANKER etc...

I need the unit numbers between these rows to fill out to the right.

Comment: I'm trying to make sense of your original post alongside this one. It looks like you want the LOCATION column to be the one sorted as unique, and the row for each LOCATION is built out using the values in UNIT #?

Comment: Yes, that is correct, the initial sample data I posted was just proof of concepts.  I want the location unique and the unit numbers built out

Comment: Try this formula: `=transpose(filter('HOURS & MILEAGE LOG'!A:A,'HOURS & MILEAGE LOG'!D:D=A2))` I think the comparison at the end might be causing the issue. If it works for the top column, use the formula dragger to apply it to the cells below it and automatically update the `A2` value at the end.

Comment: @Peter  PERFECT! a big digital high five for you

Comment: Please don't include the solution in your question. Your question post should _only_ contain your question. If an answer worked for you, please "accept" it. If you found the solution on your own, please answer your own question and answer it. Either way this acts as a sign post for future readers who have the same issue.

Comment: @Peter, one last Question, what if I wanted to Prepend the UNIT data with the data from the DESIGNATION COLUMN (column B in source) on the second sheet. Like B1 & " " A1. Is it possible to adjust the transpose function to combine two columns

Comment: You've have to try it yourself on your sheet, but possibly this: `=transpose(filter('HOURS & MILEAGE LOG'!A:B,'HOURS & MILEAGE LOG'!D:D=A2))`. Essentially filter both A and B columns using your old sheet's D column value.

Comment: thanks, did not work, it just added the B column underneath the cell containing the unit number.  I'll have to play around

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can accomplish this in two steps:

1. Create a new sheet `Sheet2` and use the following formula for A1 (or wherever you want the column to begin): `=unique(Sheet1!A:A)`. This will give you a vertical column of simply A, B, C, and D as the unique values in `Sheet1`'s A column.
2. Combine transpose and filter in the cell adjacent to each cell in `Sheet2` as follows: `=transpose(filter(Sheet1!B:B,Sheet1!A:A=A1))`. Here, you are filtering the second column of your `Sheet1` according to whether or not the letter next to in `Sheet1` matches the latter next to it in `Sheet2`. This normally prints vertically, so you use transpose to make it print horizontally, i.e. in the same row as you show above. Then, drag the formula down to apply it to each successive row.

The formulas in `Sheet2` end up looking like this:

[image: Google Sheets Formulas]

Comment: Thanks Peter! I'm almost there, please see my edit for details

Comment: Thanks for the steps, sadly I discovered this after doing it by hand but now I can reproduce in a couple of minutes what took me half an hour, because you explained how to use the sheets tools together :)

Answer (score 2):

Also two steps, assuming `256` is in B2:

1. in C2: `=COUNTIF(A$1:A2,A2)` copied down to suit
2. in D1:

   ```
   =query(A1:C8,"select A, SUM(B) group by A pivot C")
   ```

Comment: Thanks pnuts, I can get the first formula to work like: =COUNTIF('HOURS & MILEAGE LOG'!D$7:D8,'HOURS & MILEAGE LOG'!D8)
but the second one I can't get to work, see my edit for the actual source sheet structure.  I tried this:
=query('HOURS & MILEAGE LOG'D7:A8,"select D, SUM(B) group by D pivot A")
but it did not work